# How to test the parameters of a long chaining method without create tons of doubles

Tags: rspec

I have an Active Record query like so:

```
user.templates.where(id: @template_id).joins(:another_record).pluck('templates.id').uniq
```

But I just want to test that the `where` is getting called with the correct id. Is there a way to do this without having to create several doubles that just respond to the remaining methods.

Essentially I want something like

```
expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive_message_chain('templates.where').with(id: target_id).and_return(a_double_that_returns_another_double_that_responds_to_anything)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [Null Object Double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/basics/null-object-doubles):

```
a_double_that_returns_another_double_that_responds_to_anything = double.as_null_object
expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive_message_chain('templates.where').with(id: target_id).and_return(a_double_that_returns_another_double_that_responds_to_anything)
```

As a side note, I don't see any benefit from this test. It would be much better to make an integration test that would connect to a real database and check that your query is actually works and doesn't just call some AR methods.

If you can show me a little more context on what you're testing, I could give a more thoughtful advice.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try and fit this in and see if it makes sense to use. I'll also try to redact it a little bit so I can provide a bit more context.